# PHP create Multidimensional array from class function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a custom session handler for my script so I can store and manage sessions items using the database layer.

Currently the data is stored as a json object and decoded or encoded when calling or storing into the database. I was able to store using the following function on my session class:

```
private $data = array();
// Set data for the session handler. If you pass a variable
// as null, it will be deleted from the array.
function set_data($name, $data) {
    // Check if the field exists already or not
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
        // Check if the data being added is an array or not
        if (is_array($this->data[$name]) && is_array($data)) {
            $this->data[$name] = array_merge($this->data[$name], array_intersect_key($data, $this->data[$name]));
        } else {
            $this->data[$name] = $data;
        }
    } else {
        $this->data[$name] = $data;
    }
    // Remove NULL entries from the data set
    $this->data = array_filter($this->data, function($var){return $var !== null;});
    $database->update("sessions", json_encode($this->data), $this->session_id);
}
```

The issue I am running into now is that I cannot add multi-dimensional items to the list. For example, if I run the following command
`$session->set_data("cart", array("items" => array(1,2,3)));`
but then try and add a second field under cart, like so
`$session->set_data("cart", array("categories" => array("a","b","c")));`, then the array won't be expanded to add the second category and will just print out the following:

```
Array (
    [cart] => Array (
        [items] => Array (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
         )
    )
)
```

The desired output would actually be

```
Array (
    [cart] => Array (
        [items] => Array (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 3
         )
        [categories] => Array (
                [0] => a
                [1] => b
                [2] => c
         )
    )
)
```

The current code allows me to overwrite `items` array with a new array, with a string, or deleting it by setting it to `null`, but it does not allow me to add a second item under the parent (`cart` in this case).

How would I go about managing a multidimensional array from a class like this? is it recursion? what about children items further down? Thanks!

Comment: `array_intersect_key` will return an empty array in this case. Just use `$this->data[$name] = array_merge($data, $this->data[$name]);`

Comment: Actually I guess it should be: `$this->data[$name] = array_merge($this->data[$name], $data);`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this line:

```
$this->data[$name] = array_merge($this->data[$name], array_intersect_key($data, $this->data[$name]));
```

For this one:

```
$this->data[$name] = array_merge($this->data[$name], $data);
```

The first one doesn't work because there are not intersected keys between `$data` and `$this->data[$name]`, so you end getting an empty array. As a result of that, your `$this->data[$name]` is not altered.

Comment: i ended up using a recursion method as this wasn't merging their children items when i did it that way so i have a working solution now.